# Connection to host reset when accessed via VPN or behind corporate firewalls

Tags: vpn, firewall, reset

A client of mine was reporting connectivity issues from a lot of his customers who are either accessing his website from behind a corporate firewall or via VPN recently.

I did check the endpoint it there are no indications of compromise. Likely, the ASN or the IP got on a black list, which got resolved. However, still when using a VPN (from various locations) no TCP handshake can be completed (neither via HTTP/s nor via SSH) but get reset by the host immediately.

The endpoint is a Ubuntu VM hosted by Digital Ocean. ufw is running but allows SSH and HTTPS from any location. Also, when disabling ufw a similar behavior is observed.

What could be further root causes? Do VPN providers maintain their own block lists? How can I identify the root cause of the connection resets?